# Displaying information from Twig don't work propertly

Tags: php, symfony, twig, altorouter

Have problem displaying information via Twig template.

I'm using `Twig Template`, `AltoRouter`.

AltoRouter code:

```
 $router->map('GET','/[*]','Edion\Controllers\QuestionController@showCountMessage'
             ,'count_message');
```

Controller:

```
 public function showCountMessage() {
    $message = InsideMessage::where('author_id', '=', $_SESSION['user']['id'])
               ->where('author_read', '=', '0')->get();
    echo $this->twig->render('topnav.html.twig', ['messages' => count($message)]);
 }
```

`topnav.html.twig are included in all my pages`

The problem is that I don't get number of messages in my website. If I change AltoRouter code:

```
   $router->map('GET','/example','Edion\Controllers\QuestionController@showCountMessage'
               ,'count_message');
```

And I enter `sitename.com/example` it work's perfectly, but when I change to `[*]` because I want that this information would be on all of my pages, don't work.

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. Remove $router and echo from showCountMessage(). Add twig global variable and it's all working perfectly.

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove $router and echo from showCountMessage(). Add twig global variable.